# Keep Redux form values after page reload.(without submit form)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, local-storage, redux-form

redux form page set values after page reload. I'm saving the state in local storage. what i have now is after page reload values are not showing until i click on the input field. to achieve this which approach should i use?. Any taught would be nice.

[video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C3QTOFp-kR5k_SjuDUWY6gSeO_21S_4W/view?usp=sharing)

```js
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'checkoutForm',
    keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true,
    enableReinitialize: true,
})(PaymentOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue at hand correctly, I have a suggestion that may work for you.

Create an action creator that gets the localStorage

```
export const getLocalStorageData = () => dispatch => {
    const storage = localStorage.getItem('form_data')

    dispatch(...update store here)
}
```

Try connecting with `initialValues`

```
CheckoutForm = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: state.data // pull initial values from reducer
  }),
  { data: getLocalStorageData } // bind getLocalStorageData action creator
)(CheckoutForm)
```

[redux-form docs on initialValues](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/initializefromstate/) for your reference.